# Checkbox with text field in database

Tags: html, sql, database, checkbox

I have an HTML form with a check box linked to a text input. The check box enables/disables and clears the text input (don't need to save the text value if unchecked).

Should I save this information in 2 db  columns or one?

With one I figured I could use NULL if the check box is unchecked. I'm not sure what the best option is.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, field type should be `text` with `NULL` option.

`null` means checkbox was checked

empty means no text was entered